# Обход графа в глубину (DFS)

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Дан неориентированный граф. Необходимо реализовать алгоритм DFS. Код неправильно реализует поиск в глубину, не могли бы подсказать в чем проблема ?

```
n = int(input('Vertices: '))
m = int(input('Edges: '))
adj = [[0] * n for _ in range(n)]
for i in range(m):
    j, k = map(int, input().split())
    adj[j][k] =  adj[k][j] = 1

def dfs(v):
    used = [v]
    to_explore = [v]
    while to_explore:
        u = to_explore.pop()
        print (u)
        for w in range(n):
            if (adj[u][w] == 1) and (w not in used):
                used.append(w)
                to_explore.append(w)

print ('DFS')
dfs(0)
```

Пример: (Входные данные программы)
Vertices: 8
Edges: 10

- 0 2
- 2 4
- 0 4
- 0 1
- 1 5
- 1 6
- 2 6
- 4 6
- 6 7
- 7 3

Вывод:
0
4
6
7
3
2
1
5

Ожидаемый ответ: 0 1 5 6 2 4 7 3

Comment: Что не работает?

Comment: сам dfs неверно работает, для меня не очевидно почему он не работает

Comment: Вроде работает `Vertices: 5 Edges: 5   0 1   0 2    1 3    1 4   2 3   DFS  0 2 3 1 4`

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте описание неверной работы вашего кода в вопрос вместе с требуемым результатом.

Comment: @MBo работает неверно, обход должен быть таким: 0 1 3 2 4

Comment: Вовсе не должен, эти детали порядка обхода по барабану.

Comment: @MBo то есть обход графа в глубину не однозначен ?

Comment: При заданном порядке перечисления и обхода  узлов в циклах - однозначен (при рекурсивной реализации получится то же самое). Но оба приведённых порядка  являются валидными dfs. Если `for w in range(n):` заменить на обратный цикл - получится ваш вариант.

Comment: @MBo я не совсем понимаю как сделать так, чтобы dfs реализовала обход именно так, как я описал в примерах ?

Comment: Именно так - не знаю, но близко - `for w in reversed(range(n)):` 0 1 5 6 7 3 2 4

Answer (score 0):

В коде реализован алгоритм BFS(поиск в ширину). Алгоритм DFS выглядел бы так:

```
def dfs(v):
    used = [v]
    for u in range(n):
        if u not in used:
            print(u)
            used.append(u)
            dfs(u)
```